# Sorting Middle string

Tags: sql

I have the following values in a column

Name

```
Smith
Marry
Tom
Robert
Albert
```

I have to display in the following order. I want MARRY on top. For the rest of the values ordering is not matter.

Name

```
Marry
Smith
Tom
Robert
Albert
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` in `order by`:

```
order by (case when name = 'Marry' then 1 else 2 end)
```